# Multiplication based on input integer and return array- Need help in storing array while looping

Tags: java, arrays

Do multiplication based on user input integer and return array in Java.

Eg: User Input 2

```
1*1=1
1*2=2
2*1=2 
2*2=4
```

Output array should have [1,2,2,4]

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    int value = scan.nextInt();
    int totalSize= value * value ;
    int [] a= new int [totalSize];

    for(int i=1; i<=totalSize;i++)
    {
        for(int j=1;j<=value ;j++)
        {
            a[i-1]=i*j;
            }
```

How to proceed ?

Comment: This sounds very suspiciously like homework. Consider rewording your question to explain exactly what your confused with and possibly an attempt.

Comment: Yes please find my attempt .                                                                    
  Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
  int value = scan.nextInt();
  int totalSize= value * value ;
  int [] a= new int [totalSize];
  
  for(int i=1; i<=totalSize;i++)
  {
   for(int j=1;j<=value ;j++)
   {
    a[i-1]=i*j;
    }

Comment: @MichaelChoi
 Can you help what I am missing here . I need help in storing the value .I am missing something in the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
System.out.println("Enter number of entries");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        int i,j,k,index=0;
        int value = scan.nextInt();
        int totalSize= value * value ;
        int [] a= new int [totalSize];

        for(i=1; i<=value;i++) {
            for (j = 1; j <= value; j++) {
                a[index++] = i * j;
            }
        }
        for(k=0; k<totalSize;k++) {
            System.out.println(a[k]);
        }
```